# SQL Select LIKE, find similarities

Tags: sql, select, string-comparison, sql-like, hana

Is there a way with the Select LIKE operator to find similarities?
For example I have a table with following content.

```
1. 34578
2. 34878
3. 12578
```

Now I want select all values with are similar with 34X78, where X can be any number from 0 to 9. Result should be then record 1 and 2.

Also X can be on various positions and something like 3XX79 or 3X5X8 should be possible.

It can be also a solution using SQLScript on SAP HANA

Comment: Could you check for the following three conditions? 1) length of 5 characters, 2) begins with `34`, 3) ends with `78`?  Or would this not be flexible enough for you?

Comment: Fuzzy search for '34578' with a sufficiently low threshold might give you what you need, see http://scn.sap.com/thread/3362054

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the manuals HANA suports [regular expressions](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_hanaplatform/helpdata/en/b4/0d483dd34d47aa9cc89b4d8a6e617e/content.htm?frameset=/en/b4/0d483dd34d47aa9cc89b4d8a6e617e/frameset.htm&current_toc=/en/2e/1ef8b4f4554739959886e55d4c127b/plain.htm&node_id=64):

```
WHERE column LIKE_REGEXPR '34[0-9]78'
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using '_' wild card:

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable
WHERE COLUMN LIKE '34_78'
```

_ Is a wild card that does what you asked for, can be replaced with any thing.

[You can find an explanation about LIKE wildcards here.](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp)